# delete duplicates based on a combination of 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I consider a row duplicate when the combination of hash_key and load_date is repeating. I can find such rows using this CTE:

```
with w_duplicated_rows as (
    select hash_key, load_date, count(*),
    --row_number() over (partition by hash_key, load_date order by load_date desc) as row_num
    from my_table
    group by hash_key, load_date having count(*) > 1
)
```

This gives me the combinations which are being repeated in the table.

Now, I want to delete duplicates from the original `my_table`. I have another column called STATUS. While deleting duplicates, I want to delete the row after filtering on `ORDER BY STATUS DESC`. Means I want to keep the top row and remove the second one (where status is lower).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `delete from my_table where (hash_key, load_date, status) not in (
  select distinct on (hash_key, load_date) hash_key, load_date, status
  from my_table
  order by hash_key, load_date, status desc
)` ? -- assuming the columns don't have nulls in them.

Comment: @TheImpaler - which part of your query insures that ***the top row is kept*** and others removed?

Comment: @PM77-1 `distinct on (hash_key, load_date)`

Comment: Will you ever have cases where there are duplicates on the max status? If so, how will ties be broken?

Comment: yes the value of the status can be the same. it doesn't really matter. I can select any one of them. also if they aren't the same, I can just pick up any of them. First or second. That would also work for my use case @Error_2646

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign a row number to each row within the duplicate groups, ordered by `STATUS DESC`. Then, you can use a common table expression `(CTE)` to identify the rows with row numbers greater than 1 and delete them from the original table.

Here's an example query:

```sql
WITH ranked_rows AS (
    SELECT
        hash_key,
        load_date,
        STATUS,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hash_key, load_date ORDER BY STATUS DESC) AS row_num
    FROM my_table
    WHERE (hash_key, load_date) IN (
        SELECT hash_key, load_date
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY hash_key, load_date
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
)
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE (hash_key, load_date) IN (
    SELECT hash_key, load_date
    FROM ranked_rows
    WHERE row_num > 1
);
```

> Make sure to test this query on a backup before
> applying it to the entire table.

Comment: I have 215 duplicates but this would delete 430 rows. Tried by "Selecting" instead of deleting

Comment: the calculation in the CTE is correct (i.e returns 215 rows when filtered for row_num > 1) but the where clause after delete doesm't work as expected

Comment: ok, I've modified the code above, give it a try.

Comment: I don't think so. Uptil the CTE, the output is 215 rows. This would still delete 220

Comment: Hmm, ok, now I've added another fix. It uses the EXISTS clause to check for the existence of rows in the w_duplicated_rows CTE that should meet the criteria for deletion.

Comment: nah, this would still delete 430 rows. guess the row_num filtering isn't working as expected

Comment: hmm, tricky one then, could you clarify once more in detail the conditions and the expected result, maybe we're missing something crucial.

Comment: @IlliaNova The problem is the IN for the delete. This will match all combinations of hash_key and load_date that have at least one row_number greater than one.

Comment: @IlliaNova You could probably change in to (hash_key, load_date, STATUS) IN .... for the delete.

Comment: Already tried that too but that also returns the wrong number of rows. @Error_2646

Comment: @IlliaNova I can just pick any one of the two duplicates. that would also work for me

Comment: Ok, good to hear)

Answer (score 0):

If you've truly got no field to break ties maybe ctid is the best it'll get. Hard to tell if you are using postgres or redshift. Redshift appears to have a similar concept with row_id. But read the documentation.

Rationale - Basic strategy to preferentially select the duplicate with the highest status, but add the system unique identifier to break ties.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/MDBsecyC

```
create table some_test_data
  (
    hash_key varchar(255),
    load_date date,
    status integer
  );
insert into some_test_data values
  ('abc', '2024-01-01', 0),
  ('abc', '2024-01-01', 1),
  ('abc', '2024-01-01', 1),
  ('cde', '2024-01-02', 1),
  ('efg', '2024-01-03', 0),
  ('efg', '2024-01-04', 0);

with duplicates_to_delete as 
  (
    select *,
           ctid,
           row_number() over ( partition by
             hash_key,
             load_date
             order by status desc,
                      ctid desc) as rn
      from some_test_data
  )
delete from some_test_data del_target
  where exists
          (
            select 1
              from duplicates_to_delete dtd
             where del_target.hash_key = dtd.hash_key
               and del_target.load_date = dtd.load_date
               and del_target.ctid = dtd.ctid
               and dtd.rn > 1
          );
```